# GBM and 1-dim approximation

Tags: python, cart, boosting

So, I guess I am completely lost on subject of regression trees. 
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
train_X = pd.DataFrame({"A":x})
train_y = pd.Series(np.sin(x))

gbm = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=7, n_estimators=300, 
learning_rate=0.01).fit(train_X, train_y)
predictions = gbm.predict(train_X)
plt.plot(x, predictions)
plt.show()
```

The above code generates straight line as prediction. I expected some step function approximating `sin`. Any suggestions? How do regression trees work?

Answer (score 0):

With a `max_depth=7` and `n_estimators=300` you have given the model $300 \times 2^7 = 38400$ opportunities to split on your predictor.  This is well beyond the number of pixels of vertical resolution available to show a stair step shape in any graph (my macbook pro is 2880-by-1800 for the entire monitor).

Crank down those values and you'll see the stairstep.

Comment: `gbm = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=2, n_estimators=10, learning_rate=0.01).fit(train_X, train_y)` produces the same result. What parameter would you recommend?

Comment: That is very surprising, I would think that, given all your code is correct, you would certainly see the starstep nature with those parameters.  Are you sure you should be using a classifier with regression type data?

Comment: Of course, I am not sure. The goal is to understand how regression trees work, rather than get good approximation. I am even more surprised with the following example. Replace `train_y = pd.Series(np.sin(x))` with `train_y = pd.Series(x+5)`. It generates strait line at 5, while I would imagine least squares should produce straight line at 10. Can you try to reproduce the above example on your computer? I just want to make sure that I do not have any bugs in code.

Comment: I can try to reproduce a little later in the day.  In the meantime, I think `XGBRegressor` is more appropriate for your example.

Comment: I just came across http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html. So I am guessing there is a bug in XGBoost

Comment: I doubt there is a bug in xgboost, that's a library used by thousands of people and you would know about it if one of its fundamental features was broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44283/discussion-between-user1700890-and-matthew-drury).